# Second input field should not iterate. It should be displayed only once while using it in ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghhkP.png)I want the second input field should be displayed only one time. From next iteration it should skip the statement of adding input field to UI.

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let c of [1,2,3]" >
  <div class="col-6"> 
    <input type="text" name="first">`enter code here`
  </div>
  <div class="col-6"> 
    <!-- This input field should be added only one time. Next iteration it should skip this line. -->
    <input type="text" name="Second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So why put 'it' in a loop? But you can nest *NgIf too..

Comment: Putting outside loop, it's working correctly. But as part of requirement, it has to be inside the loop because it has to be pushed into a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure about your condition here. If it shouldn't be repeated, wouldn't it be better to move it outside the `*ngFor`?

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let c of [1,2,3]" >
  <div class="col-6"> 
    <input type="text" name="first">`enter code here`
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6"> 
  <input type="text" name="Second">
</div>
```

Or if for some reason you wish to have the input inside the `*ngFor` but only to render it once for the entire array, you could use [`first`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) local variable + `*ngIf`.

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let c of [1,2,3]; let first=first">
  <div class="col-6"> 
    <input type="text" name="first">`enter code here`
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" *ngIf="first"> 
    <input type="text" name="Second">
  </div>
</div>
```